# Stuttering when moving a single sprite in an XNA application

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

**Update: I have uploaded a video showing the stutter here: http://intninety.co.uk/xnastutter.mp4 you may have to look closely in the video if you are not viewing it at 1920x1080, but you'll see that there is a rather distinct stutter when moving every 2 seconds or so, I'd recommend viewing it in Windows Media Player rather than your web browser to ensure the video itself isn't choppy and thus preventing you seeing the actual stutter**

I'm recently picking up a project I started a while ago, however I am still struggling to solve the problem I left it at!

At the moment I have a very simple application which just has a single sprite on screen and is moved around using the directional keys. The problem is every two seconds or so, the game stutters and the sprite appears to jump backwards and then back forwards very quickly.

The sprite itself is a 55x33 bitmap, so isn't anything large, and the code in use is as follows. Hopefully this is enough to get the ball rolling on some ideas as to what may be the problem, if a video is required to see exactly how the stuttering looks I can put one together and upload it somewhere if need be.

As you'll see in the code it does compensate for time lost between frames by making the movement greater should it happen, however that drop is happening very consistently time wise, which is leading me to believe I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

I've tried on a few different machines but the problem persists across all of them, if anyone has any ideas or can see where it is I'm messing up it'd be **greatly** appreciated if you could point it out.

Thanks :)

**Constructor of the Game Setting up the Graphics Device Manager**

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1920;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 1080;
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
this.IsFixedTimeStep = false;
```

**Code from the Game's Update Method**

```
KeyboardState keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
GamePadState gamePad = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape)) {
    this.Exit();
}

if ((keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) || (gamePad.DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed))
{
    this.player.MoveLeft((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds); 
} else if ((keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) || (gamePad.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed))
{
    this.player.MoveRight((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
}

if ((keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)) || (gamePad.DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed))
{
    this.player.MoveUp((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
} else if ((keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down)) || (gamePad.DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed))
{
    this.player.MoveDown((float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
}

base.Update(gameTime);
```

**The "Move" Methods seen in the above Update Method**

```
public void MoveLeft(float moveBy)
{
    this.position.X -= (moveBy * this.velocity.X);
}
public void MoveRight(float moveBy)
{
    this.position.X += (moveBy * this.velocity.X);
}

public void MoveUp(float moveBy)
{
    this.position.Y -= (moveBy * this.velocity.Y);
}

public void MoveDown(float moveBy)
{
    this.position.Y += (moveBy * this.velocity.Y);
}
```

**The Game's Draw Method**

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

spriteBatch.Begin();

spriteBatch.Draw(this.player.Texture, this.player.Position, null, Color.White, this.player.Rotation, this.player.Origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);

spriteBatch.End();

base.Draw(gameTime);
```

**Edit: forgot to mention, the velocity object used in the Move methods is a Vector2**

Comment: Any reason why you are coverting to a float and then taking a float parameter, rather than just taking the int. Assuming velocity is a PointF, then Position (PointF too?) calc will still be float even if moveBy is int (it will be implicitly cast on the fly). The jump is likely to be a bad value creeping in, maybe related to floating point arithmatic? Try putting out the positions and moveby values on each call and and hopefully this will show you where the bad digit is creeping into MoveLeft/Right.

Comment: Does this 'jump' look like flashing a second-old frame? Or is it always showing the sprite displaced in a certain direction? It almost sounds like an anomaly in GameTime, though I've never heard of that happening.

Comment: The position and velocity properties are both Vector2s, the reason I've got the cast is because the X and Y properties in the Vector2 are stored as floats so I cast the TotalMilliseconds to the float for the calculation of the new position.

I'll try adding in some code to log the calls and see if there is any values that really stick out.

Comment: @KendallFrey Yes, it's as if the previous frame is being shown, but then jumps straight back to where it should be.

Comment: Try using a Debug.Assert to figure out if it's your variables moving backwards, or just the graphics.

Comment: @Wolf5370 - the cast to float is because `TotalMilliseconds` is a double (milliseconds plus fractional milliseconds) and not an int (ie: just `Milliseconds`).  I've been able to reproduce this even setting (and confirming) a target fixed time step of 1ms (was running ~0.3-0.4ms without fixed time step). So it does not look like a bug with gameTime.

Comment: Should note that I added `this.IsFixedTimeStep = true;`,  `this.TargetElapsedTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,1);` in the constructor and `if (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds != 1) outp++;` to `Update`  where outp is an `int` and confirmed the counter does not rise.  Seems almost like hicuup...weird.

Comment: Code wise it seems fine, so you need to narrow this down. Suggest setting the velocity such that you can hold down one arrow at a time for 5 seconds to check if it happens eachway. If it does, then I'd comment out the move stuff for a while and test witha simple for/next loop to move it one direction for a 5 seconds (not using the velocity etc at first) and see if it happens (tells you whether its the move code or the draw). If it still happens, then it must be the draw code. If it doesn't happen, then bring back bits at a time into the loop, i.e. add back the velocity to the loop and so on.

Comment: OK, I've tried logging the results of one of the Move methods but I don't see any erroneous figures, I've put a copy of them up on pastebin - http://pastebin.com/4PbryYg9

This one really does have me stumped!

Comment: @Wolf5370 I've added a second sprite to the application which rotates in place using a similar means of calculation and uses the exact same drawing code as the previous one, and the rotation isn't stuttering at all, runs completely fine, so I'm guessing there isn't anything wrong with the Draw call I'm making. See the code below:

`this.enemy.Rotation += (float)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds * 0.5f);`

Comment: It may also be worth me adding - if I monitor the FPS, it is constantly over 8,000, there are never any drastic drops to say below 60fps.

Comment: `graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = true;` also does not seem to change the behaviour.

Comment: The code you are showing us looks ok. What are player.Texture, player.Velocity, player.Rotation, player.Origin, and how are they changed over time? Also, could you describe the problem in more detail? How big of a distance does it jump? How many frames are affected? Is the sprite rotated at all? Does it happen more or less often depending on what you're doing or is it constant?

Comment: If new code works, then you either have to do something like I suggested to refine it down until you find the problem area more specifically, or replace the code with the new working code. Although rotation stutters would be a lot harder to see than translation ones.

Comment: @Sahuagin - player.Texture is a Texture2D, player.Velocity is a Vector2 and player.Rotation is a float. Texture is never changed, it is only assigned the once when loading the content, Velocity has it's X and Y properties altered in the Move methods I posted, and Rotation is never changed, I just have it set to 0.0f at the moment. The distance in which it jumps on screen looks around 3 maybe 4 millimetres, however it seems to vary, if it'd be of use I will record some footage and upload it for you?

Comment: @Sahuagin - also, the sprite isn't rotated and if I use short key bursts I can't see the problem, but if I hold the keys down long enough to move the sprite from one end of the screen to the other (for say 3-5 seconds) it is guaranteed to happen every time.

Comment: Is it possible to upload the project somewhere? I could probably figure it out if I could see the whole project. Things to try include: does it go away if you don't pass `TotalMilliseconds`, but pass a constant (like 150) instead? Does it go away if you replace `this.Player.Rotation` and `this.Player.Origin` in the draw call with `0`, and `new Vector2()` respectively? try to monitor this.Player.Position and see if it does or does not fluctuate when the graphic jumps.

Comment: I've played with this to death and can't figure it out. What's really odd is that I have another program (one of mine) which, although working with a more developed physics engine, can essentially be reduced to a very similar sequence of calls, and which I cannot cause to exhibit this weird glitch - as much as I cannot cause this piece of code to not exhibit it.  I draw to destination `Rectangle`s but that didn't fix this.  I use `Vector2.` math rather than direct operations on floats but that didn't fix it.  Changed most everything I could think of...

Comment: without more code I can't really help further. (are you both int0x90 and J...?) Assuming that it's not some flaw in XNA itself, you are assuming something incorrectly (this is the case when debugging any problem); since you have a false assumption, your statements that certain things are known to work are irrelevant from my perspective. I need to see code to be able to identify what you are missing.

Comment: @Sahuagin I'm not int0x90, don't know why you would think that.  I was puzzled by this problem and am trying to help solve it.  You don't need any more code - I made a new XNA project and copy/pasted everything above into it.  It is sufficient to reproduce the problem (save adding a tiny class called 'player' with a tex and a couple vector2s).

Comment: @J... hmm, if the above code is enough to reproduce the problem then this should definitely be solvable. I'll try putting it in a new project and see what I can find.

Comment: When I first ran this I ran full screen mode and saw the problem - did all my testing in windowed mode, however.  I tried again briefly this morning in full screen and it seems to have gotten better.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to replicate the issue. I get a sprite that moves smoothly across the screen with the cursor keys. Some assumptions I've had to make include: position starts at (0, 0), velocity is (.1f, .1f), rotation is a const = 0, origin is readonly = (0, 0), player is a readonly member variable, player has a loadcontent method that is called from the main loadcontent method. My guess is that this is just normal very minor stuttering caused by the OS, or that you are overheating your video card by running the frames so high (I can hear my fan speed up every time I run this).

Comment: @Sahuagin those assumptions are correct aside from the start position is at (200, 200), the velocity is (0.450f, 0.300f) and player does not have a LoadContent method, the texture is loaded in the game's LoadContent method and then passed through when constructing the player object e.g. `this.player = new CollidableObject(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Players/Green/player_green_1"), new Vector2(200, 200), 0.0f);
            this.player.Velocity = new Vector2(0.450f, 0.300f);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to see it occur once for a split second which has led me to what I think is the problem. Since you are using the raw `ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds` value as a factor for your movement, all computer lag that your program experiences will be directly applied to the motion. For example, if your computer (OS) does something else for one twentieth of a second, then the elapsed time value will accumulate to a value of ~50 milliseconds, when it is normally about 0.3 milliseconds. This would cause a frame that has 150 times more motion than a normal frame.

To cause this to happen manually, you can do the following:

```
// define a frame counter
private int mCounter;

...

protected override void Update(GameTime pGameTime)
{
   // save the elapsed time value
   float time = (float)pGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

   ...

   // force a long frame every 2500th frame (change depending on your framerate)
   if (mCounter++ > 2500)
   {
      mCounter = 0;
      time = 75; // about 225 times longer frame
   }

   ...

   // use the time value in your move calls
   if ((keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) || (gamePad.DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed))
      mPlayer.MoveLeft(time);
```

To prevent this from happening, (aside from setting `IsFixedTimeStep = true;`, which would fix it immediately; but assuming you want `IsFixedTimeStep` to be `false`), you should use a time value, as above, but cap it. It's up to you to determine the proportion of elapsed time to motion and to determine what is a good amount of time to allow to pass per frame. Ex:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime pGameTime)
{
   // save the elapsed time value
   float time = (float)pGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
   if (time > 1)
      time = 1;

   ...

   if ((keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) || (gamePad.DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed))
      mPlayer.MoveLeft(time);

   ...
```

While that will correct the issue for your current program, your frames are only at 0.3ms each since there is not a lot happening. Once there is more to your game, more time will be elapsing per frame, and you will want the cap to be much higher than 1ms.

***EDIT:*** To be clear, this is 'downtime' from your CPU/OS. It's not going to go away*, it's just up to you whether to jump ahead a bunch when it happens (which can cause problems if the elapsed time ever makes it to 2000ms, for example), or to cap these spikes and let them cause lag; either way there is going to be a 'hole' in your motion that you can't fill. This really is normal, and it's not as critical as it seems. Once there is more happening in your game, it will become less and less noticeable. It stands out strongly at the moment particularly because there are only two graphics present and nothing else happening.

*(Actually, you might look for other applications and processes that you can close to keep the CPU from being borrowed by some other program, but since you are using a multi-tasking OS, you are never going to be guaranteed to have the CPU to yourself.)

Comment: I've tried capping the total milliseconds but it hasn't stopped the issue, likewise I've tried with IsFixedTimeStep set to true and fixing the factor in which to move by but the problem still persists.

I have uploaded a video here to demonstrate what it is I am seeing: http://intninety.co.uk/xnastutter.mp4

Comment: I think you're right, I've taken some of the examples from MSDN and they all do their position calculations in this same way and all suffer from the same kind of stutter. I suppose I have never noticed it in past projects as like you said once more stuff is going on it most likely will be less noticable. I also don't think I've had sprites that move this fast before that are under the user's control.

Thank you and everyone else that put in the time and effort to help me try to nail this one on the head, it was greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

*Update Again*

Just had a thought. Have you ever checked that `(float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds` does not result in Infinity or a negative number? The elapsed time becoming negative would explain your sprite jumping back then forward.

Its the keyboard. You can prove this by changing moving left and right to left mouse and right mouse click.  Use the keydown and keyup triggers to set a state instead of iskeydown.

Update:

It appears there are a few things that cause "stuttering" in XNA. I thought for sure your issue was the keyboard problem one. However, I can only assume you've tested your code with the GamePad also and it suffers the same.

There is another problem with `IsFixedTimeStep` but you already have that set to false. A quick google search suggests there are more than a few people with these types of problems without any clear fix.

There is a long discussion at http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/9934.aspx?PageIndex=6

Other things to look at:

Try restricting your frame rate to 60 fps. There isn't any reason to go above that anyways. One power suggests that a 2d app that does nothing could stall the graphics pipeline with a significantly high throughput.

Check to see if IsSlowRunning is ever called. Garbage collection and Chaos Theory could cause this to be set. I

Comment: I tested with a game pad but it also still gets the same stuttering. 

I have previously tried setting IsFixedTimeStep to true in order to limit to 60fps, however it was still visible and resulted in the general movement not being as smooth too.

I'll add some monitoring of the IsSlowRunning flag and get back to you, but the FPS never drops significantly, it's always above 8,000. And if I add the second object I mentioned that rotates on the spot, that will always be rotating smoothly, even when the stutter occurs with the player object

Comment: I've tested it to see if IsSlowRunning gets set to true, however it doesn't seem to happen, even though the stuttering persists.

I have uploaded a video of the stuttering occurring in case it will help demonstrate exactly what it is that I am seeing, you can see it here: http://intninety.co.uk/xnastutter.mp4

I'd recommend viewing it in Windows Media Player, as the video is a bit choppy otherwise if viewing in your browser.